# Waiting for background programs to close- fix?

Tags: windows-7, skype

I have this problem:

[image: example]

I've had it for a couple of years, but now my computer *always* does this, and the only program which is ever shown on this screen is Skype.
I've tried to reinstall Skype, but this hasn't solved this issue, so I don't really know where to fix this...

I'm normally good with computers and pretty much an expert, but this has stumped me.

Is there a way to make Windows immediately terminate the background programs without showing me this screen (it really annoys me sometimes, and sometimes hangs for 30 seconds or more), or to fix this problem within Skype?

My computer is a laptop and it's pretty fast, but it's pretty much dwarfed by newer computers (the laptop is a 4 year old Medion Akoya X7811 with 1st-gen Core i7) and it shouldn't be doing this. Almost every program runs fine on it, yet it always stalls on this screen.

Yes, I know this question has been asked before, but I would generally like to make Skype stop causing this problem (is there a way to switch it to a foreground process?) instead of modifying the registry. This laptop is my primary laptop and I use it for my business, and do not want to break it.

*I'm not sure if this site is the right place to ask this question, if it isn't, please notify me instead of downvoting my question.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force Windows to ignore stalls on programs and just terminate them immediately. As an administrator run this command in the Command Prompt.

`REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v "AutoEndTask" /t REG_SZ /d 1 /f`

Comment: Although a registry modification wasn't ideal, this worked. I've backed up my registry just in case.

Comment: It might be worth looking into the Event Logs at the time the shutdown request is made and you might be able to find clues to help narrow it down. It doesn't matter how fast your machine is, if there is a bug in the code of a program that's supposed to respond, the system will just wait until the program sorts itself, however its logic is laid out. Good luck.